# simple mysql function syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql, function, syntax

I cant figure outt the error in this function that i wrote. I suspect that it must be something with type casting. i tried to comment part by part to see where the error may be and it was somewhere after the first IF and before return. I would really appreciate if someone could help me figure it out. the error is 1064 and it says that syntax is missing near ' ' line 33.

```
 DELIMITER $$



CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `substation1`(`subofficecode` INT,`productcat` VARCHAR(5),`ALN` INT(1)) RETURNS VARCHAR(10)

READS SQL DATA

BEGIN

 DECLARE substation_ID VARCHAR(10);

 DECLARE pcat VARCHAR(2);

 DECLARE  i INT;



 IF (LENGTH (subofficecode) < 3) THEN

            SET substation_ID= CONCAT ('0',subofficecode);

 ELSE IF (LENGTH (subofficecode) < 2) THEN

            SET substation_ID= CONCAT ('00',subofficecode);

 ELSE

            SET substation_ID= CONCAT('',subofficecode);

 END IF;



 IF (STRCMP(productcat,'REF')=0) THEN

            SET pcat = '11';

 ELSE IF (STRCMP(productcat,'DF')=0) THEN

            SET pcat='12';

 ELSE IF (STRCMP(productcat,'MWO')=0) THEN

            SET pcat='13';

 ELSE IF (STRCMP(productcat,'WM')=0) THEN

            SET pcat='14';

 ELSE IF (STRCMP(productcat,'SPLIT')=0) THEN

            SET pcat='15';

 ELSE

            SET pcat='16'; 

 END IF;



SET i=(SELECT MAX(substationid) FROM substation) + 1;

SET substation_ID=CONCAT(substation_ID,pcat,ALN,i);



RETURN substation_ID;



END$$



DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: SET substation_ID=CONCAT(substation_ID,pcat,ALN,i); the 4th last line. but i commented it our and then tried to reutrn '123' and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bare minimum, when chaining conditions in an `IF` statement, the right syntax is `ELSEIF` not `ELSE IF`.

> ```
> IF search_condition THEN statement_list
>     [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
>     [ELSE statement_list]
> END IF
> ```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html for the supported syntax

Comment: i dont have access to the actual server but i checked the syntax after removing space on my wamp's phpmyadmin and it worked. will let you know tomorrow if it works on the actual server. i sound stupid because its my first function ever and it was assigned by my supervisor at work

Comment: @user1451836 There is *plenty* of room for improving your SQL function. You should perhaps take a look at [`LPAD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) or why not [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_field) before tomorrow ;)

Comment: Thank you, the function worked and fit well into my task. i looked up lpad and field() today after submitting it. i'll keep that in mind before my next task. thanks again :)